# Android Contact permission denied even if it is declared on Android manifest

Tags: android

Maybe you can help me to figure out what cause problem...
I have simple app, that add new contact after user clicked the button.

But I have an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{49af1fb 14363:com.example.gszczepanski.eduandroid/u0a59} (pid=14363, uid=10059) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                                                         at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1999)
                                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1421)
                                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1225)
                                                                                         at com.example.gszczepanski.eduandroid.ContactDetailsActivity.addNewContact(ContactDetailsActivity.java:54)
                                                                                         at com.example.gszczepanski.eduandroid.ContactDetailsActivity.addContact(ContactDetailsActivity.java:24)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Even if I declared read and write contact permissions in my Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gszczepanski.eduandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I guess maybe I declared something wrong in my method code? Here it is:

```
private void addNewContact(UserContactData contactData){
        String name = contactData.getFirstName() + " " + contactData.getLastName();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 001);
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, contactData.getPhoneNumber());
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, name);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA1, contactData.getEmailAddress());

        getContentResolver().insert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

I will be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Are you running Android 6.0?

Comment: Yes, default visual adapter on Android Studio.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/10/android-60-runtime-permission-model.html)

Comment: Then make sure that you've correctly applied runtime permission.

Comment: Ok, everything is clear. I just have to write some more code along my declared permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android 6.0 or above, you have to ask user for some permission(that can access user's private data) at run time.

[See this: Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling your project against api 23 - you have to ask for that permission in runtime for Android 6.0 devices. See [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Above MarshMallow you have to do Runtime permission like below..

```
    String[] mPermission = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS};
    private static final int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 1;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[0])
                        != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[1])
                                != MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                     ) 
                    // Request missing contact permission.
// It will show a dialogue
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            mPermission, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);


Handle the success code in onRequestPermissionResult:

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }
```